# Merging time series data of different frequencies

Tags: pandas, time-series, resampling

I have 5 min intraday stock price data which I downsample by the following code:

```
ohlc = {                                                                                                             
'Open':'first',                                                                                              
'High':'max',                                                                                                     
'Low':'min',                                                                                                        
'Close': 'last',                                                                                                    
'Volume': 'sum'
}

d1_data = min5_data.resample('1d').apply(ohlc).dropna()
```

what I am trying to achieve is to merge the 5 min intraday and day data and match it by date (basically same values on 5 min interval for the whole duration of the trading day or 78 values in total). My idea is to have a reference for the opening price and day range expressed by High and Low.

It is not necessary to go thru resampling if there is another way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
merged_data = pd.concat([min5_data, d1_data], axis=1).ffill()
```

Thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
d1_data = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame([],
                             index = pd.date_range(start = '2020-01-01', 
                                                   end = '2020-01-31', 
                                                   freq = 'D')
                                                   ),
                  min5_data, 
                  how = 'left', 
                  right_index = 'True',
                  left_index = 'True')
```